# Performance issues with initialScrollOffset on ListView.builder

Tags: performance, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm using `ListView.builder` with a couple of `Card` and `Text` widgets. When tapping a button I'm opening a page which includes the mentioned list and scroll to a specific widget in this list. I'm doing that through attaching a custom `ScrollController` to the `ListView.builder`.

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: count,
    controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: height),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return isHeader(index) ? Text(...) : Card(...); 
    }
)
```

`height` is based on the amount of widgets and their fixed height. It's working, but the performance is bad and causing a lag of ~ one second when pressing the button to open the page. If I don't use `initialScrollOffset` the performance is fine. The performance drop is due to the fact, that all previous items are also built until the `initialScrollOffset` is reached.

Is it possible to initialize a list on a specific position without building all previous items? If not, is there a good workaround to achieve this behavior in a fluent way?

Comment: May I know the `itemCount`?

Comment: @10101010 around 60

Comment: Do you know the height of the `Card`(the height of each row)?

Comment: @10101010 yes, I do

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` has a property called `itemExtent` specifying which should significantly improve the performance. It basically expects the height of the row in the list.

E.g code

```
ListView.builder(
    itemCount: count,
    controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: height),
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Card(...); 
    },
    itemExtend: 30.0 // Height of the row
)
```

For more info check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/itemExtent.html).

Comment: I should've mentioned that I have two types of widgets in the list (`Card` and `Text` elements), so two different element heights.. thought it's not relevant. I tried using `itemExtent` and really had a performance improvement, but sadly it's not suited for my use case.

Comment: I wonder what is going in the `Card`(or the rows in the list) to make a list of 60 slow.

Comment: A workaround could be to show nothing(or a loader) initially and then display the list.

Comment: Each `Card` contains a couple of AutoSizeText widgets (https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text), which makes it slow. How would you detect the finished build and scroll to switch from displaying a loader to a list? I started using ScrollContainers' `animateTo` instead of `initialScrollOffset`, which is taking the workload from the initial build and spreading it over a timeframe. At least the lag is gone.